# FFmpeg downloading entire live stream when making a small clip

Tags: video, ffmpeg

### Setup

I'm using FFmpeg to generate video clips from M3U8 videos. The command looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss <start> -i <1080p-chunklist-url> -c:v copy -c:a copy -t <duration> -f mp4 -y out.mp4
```

For example, to create a 30-second clip starting at the 5-minute mark for a particular video, the command would be:

```
ffmpeg -ss 300 -i https://example.com/path/to/1080p/index.m3u8 -c:v copy -c:a copy -t 30 -f mp4 -y out.mp4
```

Some caveats I'm already aware of:

- If `-ss` comes **after** `-i` then FFmpeg will attempt to download the entire M3U8 instead of just the relevant TS files, and will parse the entire video contents looking for the exact timestamp. By putting `-ss` **before** -i FFmpeg uses "seek points", which with HLS videos means it looks at the M3U8 and only downloads relevant TS files
- TS file boundaries function as "seek points" in HLS, so if a TS file starts at 4:51 and the next TS file starts at 5:01, this command will start the clip at 4:51 instead of 5:01 (it prefers the first seek point before the requested time)
- The `-t` parameter sets an exact clip duration instead of an ending position, so in the above example of a clip starting at 4:51 the same clip would end at 5:21 instead of 5:30

In theory I can utilize `-to` instead of `-t` to specify an ending time of 5:30, however in practice this hasn't worked. Also in theory I can force `-accurate_seeking` to discard the contents from 4:51 to 5:00 and start the clip where I wanted it, but I learned this only works for transcodes and not transmux

Now to the meat of my problem:

### Problem

When the M3U8 URL provided is a **live** stream (no `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` tag) then FFmpeg does not behave correctly. On FFmpeg versions 4.2.1 and earlier, it starts by downloading the TS file containing my clip segment, then proceeds to download ***every*** TS file in the M3U8 then hangs while waiting for new TS files to become available, downloading them as they appear - even ***hours*** after the end of the section I wanted to clip. On FFmpeg version 4.2.2 and later, I can create clips so long as they end before the second-to-last TS file. If the live stream currently has 20 minutes of video data and I create a clip from 19:30 - 19:40 (ending right at the start of the second-to-last TS file, assuming a 10-second TS file duration) then it will behave the same as 4.2.1: waiting infinitely to download the entire video.

The "2 TS files from the end" rule I believe is related to FFmpeg's initial probe of the video to get stream data. In the aforementioned 20-minute long video, if I make a clip from 3:00 to 3:30 (well before the end of the stream) it will first download TS files 119 and 120 (19:40-19:50 and 19:50-20:00), then it displays a list of the streams in the video (audio, video, metadata), ***then*** it downloads TS files 19 - 21 (containing the actual data I want for my clip)

Is there a way to fix it so I can properly make clips of sections near the "end" of live M3U8s?

Comment: I haven't found a solution for this problem, but I have found a work-around. I'm downloading the M3U8 on my own and parsing it to determine which TS files include the segment I want to clip, then I'm downloading the TS files to a temporary directory and using FFmpeg's "concat" protocol to read in all of the TS files as a single video and extract my clip